# Update values in identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I override the `identity` column in MSSQL? I tried :

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT GeoCountry ON
    UPDATE GeoCountry SET CountryID = 18 WHERE CountryID = 250
```

But I get back a

> Line 2: Cannot update identity column 'CountryID'.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are trying to perform an update, not inserting new rows.

In order to do that, you will need to set `identity_insert` ON *and* copy the row you want to update to a new row with the new ID value, then delete the old row (assuming no FK is referencing it)

Something along the lines of:

```
set identity_insert GeoCountry on
go

insert into GeoCountry (all columns including IDentity column) 
     select 18, (all columns except IDentity column)
     from GeoCountry where CountryID = 250 

-- Delete will only work if no referencing FK's
delete GeoCountry where CountryID = 250

set identity_insert GeoCountry off
go
```

[Given that you are trying to update it, that would suggest it is still in use (i.e. by referencing FK's) and that makes things more complicated...]

Comment: It worked for me too but the part in brackets was confusing in first place. Therfore to be a bit more precise:

insert into GeoCountry (column1, column2, columnN) 
     select 18, column2, columnN
     from GeoCountry where CountryID = 250

Answer (score 12):

You cannot update the Identity Column in SQL Server.    You have to delete the original record, then Insert the record with the Identity value because there is no support for updating an identity value.

set Identity_Insert [ColumnName] On
Insert identity and additional information previously stored in that record 
set Identity_Insert [ColumnName] Off

Comment: +1 IMO this is the correct answer.  When posed with the question "How do I update the identity value" it is an important detail that you cannot in fact UPDATE the value but must DELETE and re-INSERT.  The accepted answer fails in this respect.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to update an identity column here is one possible approach:

- In SQL Server Management Studio, open the table in design view, disable "Identity Specification > Is Identity" on the column
- Perform updates
- Enable "Identity Specification > Is Identity" on the column

Do a `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('<table name>')` to see if it returns the highest id that is currently present in the table.

Comment: This method is the nicer way to go if you have foreign keys with cascading updates because you get the updates for "free".

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this in one statement using delete into, this has the benefit of eliminating any error copying/moving the row data, for example

```
set identity_insert [dbo].[MyTableName] on

delete from [dbo].[MyTableName]
output 
<new-id-value-here>,
[deleted].[Col1], 
[deleted].[Col2], 
[deleted].[Col3], 
into 
[dbo].[MyTableName] (
[IdColumnName], 
[Col1], 
[Col2], 
[Col3])
where
[IdColumnName]=<old-id-value-here>

set identity_insert [dbo].[MyTableName] off
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reenumerate the values of an identity field, because for instance the values have gone mad, just do as follows:

- open table in design mode
  click on Identity Specification

  mark (is identity) as NO
  (Your identity field is still a PK)

  close and save design
- open table in edit mode
  Change the values of your Identity field as desired 
  (just be aware you cannot have duplicate values)
- Close the table and open it again in design mode 
  Replace your identity field (is identity) to Yes.

  Close the table and you are done.