# Deleting identity row of datagridview control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have done a project for a jewelry shop in vb.net . Right now almost it has been done. But the problem is, If i want to delete a row in datagridview control , the next identity rows' s.no should get decreased as well as in sql table for it.Please help me with the code.

Thanks!!!

Comment: try something first ... google will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge generally we cannot update the identity column

you can go through 
[Update values in identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947453/override-identity-column)

other alternate could be i dont know whether it will work or not, but you can give a try

on delete trigger of table

you can set identity seed off, then fire query to update with its -1 value
and then find the max value of column and reset your identity by doing identity again on and with this command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 34)
```