# Update identity column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to update my identity column Id ?
I get the 
Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update identity column 'Id'.

when i try to update id

```
update [WarehouseReports].[Reports]
  set Id=Id+1
  where Id=20
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Can you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3947453/2451726